# Sound default keeps going back to HDMI/DisplayPort 2

Tags: sound, 19.10

I'm on latest U19.10 and a curious problem came with this new version: I cannot keep my Sound, Output Device choice to stay on Headphones - Build-in Audio. It always switches back to HDMI/DisplayPort 2. Lock screen, sleep, logout, reboot -- any change kicks it back to HDMI/DisplayPort 2 ... which is a tinny built-in speaker in my monitor. I'm on default Gnome UI on a Thinkpad T450.

Answer (score 7):

Solution from here helped me.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1850887

Commented out "load-module module-switch-on-connect" in /etc/puslse/default.pa

Comment: can confirm that this worked for me too. Thank you for tracking down the bug report

Comment: Amazing! It worked for me too. Thank you!

Comment: Oh Thanks!!
This is worked to me too. =D

Comment: I have the same problem on  20.04, but unfortunately this did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

the workaround which works for me is to choose sub-option which is not handled by monitor for example surround sound 5.1

After that please,  change to another sound source.

Should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04, and for some reason the output device (Settings -> Sound) was not selected to be the built-in speakers. Once I chose that, I got the speakers back.

[image]